# Upload to DB & server, how come this does not work?

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to make a page for uploading a image to a server, and store info in a SQL db. But the SQL part of it, does not work. Can somebody, please help me locate the errors of my way?

PHP Part:

```
include 'db.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$uploadfile=$_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"];
$folder="images/";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"],"$folder".$_FILES["upload_file"]["name"]);

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=storfanger2017', $username, $password);

$query = "INSERT INTO stor_2017 (image_name, image_size, image_type, image_content ) ".
"VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content')";

query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
}
```

HTML Part:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form').ajaxForm(function() {
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="upload_file" name="upload_file" />
<input type="submit" name='submit_image' value="Upload Image"/>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Uploading to server works fine, but sadly the sql part is still giving me a lot of trouble.

Comment: Have you defined what `$fileName`, `$fileSize`, `$fileType` and `$content` are? Also, when you execute your insert query it should be `$conn->query($query);`

Comment: `query($query) or die('Error, query failed');` is not running the query, since you declared $conn as a PDO Object, you need to do `$conn->query($query)`

Comment: Use prepared statements, you are at risk of SQL injection. Also you don't seem to be declaring those variables you're inserting.

Comment: Okay, so i have changed it to: $conn->query($query)

Comment: @Juned
Okay, so i have changed it to: $conn->query($query) this seems to be a start. 
How do you mean define?

And what about prepared statements, not sure how to approach that either.